# Strange function-like property – can someone explain this piece of Swift code?

Tags: swift

I found this piece of code regarding sections in a table view in order to make an index in a table view:

```
class User: NSObject {
    let namex: String
    var section: Int?

    init(name: String) {
        self.namex = name
    }
}

// custom type to represent table sections
class Section {
    var users: [User] = []

    func addUser(user: User) {
        self.users.append(user)
    }
}

// raw user data
let names = [
    "Clementine",
    "Bessie",
    "Annis",
    "Charlena"
]

// `UIKit` convenience class for sectioning a table
let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation() as UILocalizedIndexedCollation

// table sections
var sections: [Section] {
    // return if already initialized
    if self._sections != nil {
        return self._sections!
    }

    // create users from the name list
    var users: [User] = names.map { namess in
        var user = User(name: namess)
        user.section = self.collation.sectionForObject(user, collationStringSelector: "namex")
        return user
    }

    // create empty sections
    var sections = [Section]()
    for i in 0..<self.collation.sectionIndexTitles.count {
        sections.append(Section())
    }

    // put each user in a section
    for user in users {
        sections[user.section!].addUser(user)
    }

    // sort each section
    for section in sections {
        section.users = self.collation.sortedArrayFromArray(section.users, collationStringSelector: "namex") as [User]
    }

    self._sections = sections

    return self._sections!

}
var _sections: [Section]?
```

The part that I didn't understand is this:

```
// table sections
var sections: [Section] {
    // return if already initialized
    if self._sections != nil {
        return self._sections!
    }

    // etc...

    return self._sections!

}
var _sections: [Section]?
```

My questions are:

What does that mean `var sections: [Section] { }`? I guess it's not a function as there is no `func` keyword in front.

What is this `var _sections: [Section]`? What's the reason to place an `_` in front?

Comment: Is it not referring to the `type`?

Comment: @Nico – as it happens, you could solve a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447687/how-to-trigger-a-break-when-an-array-is-empty) you posted using a related concept (`didSet`) to the computed property you’re asking about here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very similar to a function despite the absence of keywords – it’s a [computed property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259).

These look like variables, but act like functions.  They can be read-only (`get` but not `set`), or can have both a `get` and a `set` version.  Here’s a simpler example:

```
var y = 3

var x: Int {
    get { return 2*y }
}

println(x)  // prints 6
y += 1
println(x)  // prints 8

var z: Int {
    get { return y }
    set(newVal) { y = newVal }
}

println(z)  // prints 4
z = 10      // sets y to 10
println(x)  // prints 20 (2*10)
```

When it’s only a `get`, you can omit the keyword, which is how it’s being done in the version in your question.  The declaration of `x` above could have been written without it:

```
var x: Int {
    return 2*y
}
```

The `var _sections` in your example is playing a similar role to the `y` variable in the above code – it’s the underlying data from which the computed property result is derived.  The reason for the `_` is just to indicate that it is a internal implementation detail.  The underscore’s not meaningful to Swift itself, that’s just a naming convention people use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations. I actually already knew those computed properties but not enough I guess, I didn't make the link. And thanks for editing the question, I'll try to be more concise for the next one.

Answer (score 1):

It's a read-only computed property. They act like properties, but are computed each time. You can read more about it [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_386). Check out the section on "Computed Properties" as well as the "Read-Only Computed Properties" section to understand the shorthand.